# Remove child products from woocommerce category page

Tags: categories, loop, pages, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a taxonomy template that display products from both parent and child terms, how can I show only the products belonging to the parent terms?

I'm trying to modify somehow this part of code:

```
            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

and how can I show only the products that belong to the current taxonomy?

Answer (score 4):

you want to display only parent category products and remove the child category products. Add the following lines of code at the end of **your theme’s functions.php** file.

```
function exclude_product_cat_children( $wp_query ) {
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 
            'tax_query', array( array (
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                'include_children' => false
            ) )
        );
    }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Patel Jignesh, i googled this code before asking question, tried this, modified functions.php but had no luck - simply doesn't work at all. I dont know why. maybe there is interferention between this filter and "woocommerce product filter" plugin =(

Comment: i am testing this code is work fine for me. you can add priority into filter hook. `add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children',99);` i hope it's work