# WooCommerce. How To Exclude Subcategory Products From Category Listing Page

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

i found this code on other post, on youtube and git too..

https://gist.github.com/ibndawood/17ade59c2f856a59e42a5ebf91fbb357

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUkez45GEk

[Remove child products from woocommerce category page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275213/remove-child-products-from-woocommerce-category-page)

```
function exclude_product_cat_children( $wp_query ) {
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 
            'tax_query', array( array (
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                'include_children' => false
            ) )
        );
    }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

But it breaks admin products search in backend. Doesn't show results.

Not sure how I can accomplish this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a query to run on the admin you can call the conditional function [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) to check, if it returns true you can just return out of the function. Additionally, [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) is an action hook.

```
function exclude_product_cat_children( $wp_query ) {

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {

        $wp_query->set( 
            'tax_query', array( array (
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                'include_children' => false
            ) )
        );

    }
}  
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks..